# Qt: Curve editor or something similar?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, curve, curve-fitting

I'm using Qt4.8 via PyQt in a Python application. Everything is working fine :-) But I need to present the user with some kind of curve editor, these widgets commonly found in image editing programs for adjusting contrast or color or stuff like this.

So I basically need a widget, which displays a curve with axes and stuff like that and the user should be able to "drop" points onto the curve and adjust the curve.

I thought I could use matplotlib for this, but as far as I see it doesn't provide any "editing" capability...

Comment: Seems like you're after a ready-made solution for a very specific problem. You'd be relying on either someone having created exactly the UI element you're looking for (a quick google doesn't show up anything useful) or having to repurpose something similar (plenty of possibilities for the creation of bugs, inefficiencies, etc.). Why not create the widget yourself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do curve editor with matplotlib. See for example this YouTube video: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nCv_MhaeFo8

And then check the event handling examples: http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/examples/event_handling/index.html

Comment: Ah well I guess I can realise it in the same way for Qt, too. Many thanks! :)

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a Qt curve editor with OpenGL widget, you can try it.

http://www.shannap.com/qt-curve-editor-en.html

Comment: That one looks really nice. The solution I developed went with QGraphicsView and used scipy Spline to create a nice spline from the user-dropped points. The project in question sadly never came out of early alpha…

Answer (score 1):

What you probably want is the qwt toolbox. It's like matplotlib for Qt.

http://qwt.sourceforge.net/

It has all kind of neat funcitonality for plots and graphs. Though you won't get the exact thing you need without creating your own subclasses.

Comment: The Python bindings of Qwt seem to be broken, at least they're not working for me...